# ExpressJs with TypeScript - passing data between middlewares

Tags: typescript, express, middleware

I'm writing my first expressJs app using TypeScript. I got got static middleware method for token validation, where I need pass data to the next middleware:

```
    static verifyAccessToken(req: Request, resp: Response, next: NextFunction) {
        const AUTH_TOKEN = AccessTokenValidator.getTokenFromHeader(req, resp);

        jwt.verify(AUTH_TOKEN, Config.JWT_SECRET, async (error: VerifyErrors | null, payload: any) => {
            if (error) {
                resp.status(401).send({message: "Token is invalid"});
            }
            // @ts-ignore
            req.userRole = payload.rol;
            next();
        });
    }
```

How can I pass data to next middleware correctly, without using "@ts-ignore"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add custom express request type definition by creating a `.d.ts` file

Create `express.d.ts` on your root project folder, and put

```
declare namespace Express {
   export interface Request {
       userRole?: string // I use string for example, you can put other type
   }
}
```

Comment: This solution fixes the error messages in the IDE, but still leads to compile errors

Answer (score 2):

```
  static verifyAccessToken(req: Request, resp: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    const AUTH_TOKEN = AccessTokenValidator.getTokenFromHeader(req, resp);

    jwt.verify(AUTH_TOKEN, Config.JWT_SECRET, async (error: VerifyErrors | null, payload: any) => {
        if (error) {
            resp.status(401).send({message: "Token is invalid"});
        }
        // @ts-ignore
        resp.locals.userRole = payload.rol;
        next();
    });
}
```

Please use locals to pass value to next middleware and it will not show typescript error and it will be easier to access it.

Comment: the best solution so far

Answer (score 0):

```
class CustomResponse extends Response{
    public token?:string;
}
```

then proceed with...

```
static verifyAccessToken(req:Request , resp: CustomResponse, next: NextFunction) {
        const AUTH_TOKEN = AccessTokenValidator.getTokenFromHeader(req, resp);

        jwt.verify(AUTH_TOKEN, Config.JWT_SECRET, async (error: VerifyErrors | null, payload: any) => {
            if (error) {
                resp.status(401).send({message: "Token is invalid"});
            }
            // @ts-ignore
            req.userRole = payload.rol;
            next();
        });
    }
```

You can uses this as a temporary solution or a quick dirty fix

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a custom interface that extends the request with the data I am passing.  then use this custom interface on all requests expecting it.

```js
interface myRequest extends Request {
  someInfo: string
}

router.use((req: myRequest, res: Response, next) => {
  req.someInfo = 'my cool string'
})

router.get('/test', (req: myRequest, res: Response) => {
  res.send(req.someInfo)
})
```

This works very nicely for me

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your project. (Works for me)

```
export {};

declare module 'express-serve-static-core' {
  export interface Request {
    locals?: Record<string, any>;
  }
}
```

then...

```
app.use((req, res) => {
    req.locals = {myVariable: 12}
});
app.use((req, res) => {
    console.log(req.locals.myVariable)
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).